# How to code/implement AWS Batch?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-batch

I am pretty new to AWS Batch. I have prior experience of batch implementation.
I gone through [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/what-is-batch.html) link and got how to configure a batch on AWS.

I have to implement simple batch which will read incoming pipe separated file, read out data from that file, perform some transformation on that data and then save each line as a separate file in S3.

But I didn't find any document or example where I could see the implementation part. All or atleast most document talks only about AWS batch configuration.

Any idea from coding/implementation part? I would be using Java for implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you. The code is in python though!
[AWSLABS/AWS-BATCH-GENOMICS](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-batch-genomics)

Answer (score 0):

AWS Batch is running your Docker containers as jobs, so the implementation is not limited to the languages.

For Java, you could have some jars copied to your `Dockerfile`, and providing a entry point or `CMD` to start your code when the job is started in AWS Batch.